# Difference between an implementation of 'when' as a function vs. as a macro

Tags: macros, scheme, mit-scheme

What exactly is different between these implementations of 'when'?

```
(define-syntax when
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ pred b1 ...)
     (if pred (begin b1 ...)))))
```

vs.

```
(define (my-when pred b1 ...)
  (if pred (begin b1 ...)))
```

For example, when 'my-when' is used in this for loop macro:

```
(define-syntax for
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (i from to) b1 ...)
     (let loop((i from))
       (my-when (< i to)
                  b1 ...
                  (loop (+ i 1)))))))
```

an error occurs:

> (for (i 0 10) (display i))
>
> ; Aborting!: maximum recursion depth exceeded

I do not think 'when' can be implemented as a function, but I do not know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheme has strict semantics.

This means that all of a function's parameters are evaluated before the function is applied to them.

Macros take source code and produce source code - they don't evaluate any of their parameters.

(Or, well, I suppose they do, but their parameters are syntax - language elements - rather than what you normally think of as values, such as numbers or strings. Macro programming is meta-programming. It's important to be aware of which level you're programming at.)

In your example this means that when `my-when` is a function, `(loop (+ i 1))` must be evaluated before `my-when` can be applied to it.
This leads to an infinite recursion.

When it's a macro, the `my-when` form is first replaced with the equivalent `if`-form

```
 (if (< i to)
     (begin
         b1 ...
         (loop (+ i 1))))
```

and then the whole thing is evaluated, which means that `(loop (+ i 1))` only gets evaluated when the condition is true.

Comment: Nice explanation! Can you clarify why the (loop (+ i 1)) only gets evaluated when the condition is true? To me, it looks like it would only be evaluated if the condition is false since the 'when' macro doesn't seem to "use" the loop in its if statement.

Comment: @wes The loop is part of the "..:" in the `my-when` macro. I hope the edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement `when` as a procedure like you did, then all arguments are evaluated. In your `for` implementation, the evaluation would be processed like this:

1. evaluate `(< i to)`
2. evaluate expansion result of `b1 ...`
3. evaluate `(loop (+ i 1))` <- here goes into infinite loop!
4. evaluate `my-when`

Item 1-3 can be reverse or undefined order depending on your implementation but the point is nr. 4. If `my-when` is implemented as a macro, then the macro is the first one to be evaluated.

If you really need to implement with a procedure, then you need to use sort of delaying trick such as thunk. For example:

```
(define (my-when pred body) (if (pred) (body)))
(my-when (lambda () (< i 10)) (lambda () (display i) (loop (+ i 1))))
```